# make a hierarchical structure for instances of a model in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

In the `User` model I added a column named `supervisor` that can hold another **user_id** for each user.

In fact each User can have a supervisor user that specified by that column.

For that I added a `hierarchical` method like this :

```
    protected function hierarchical($users)
    {
        $users = $users->toArray();

        $nestedKeys = array();

        foreach ($users as $key => $node) {
            $supervisor_id = $node['supervisor']['user_id'];
            $index         = array_search($supervisor_id, array_column($users, 'user_id'));

            if (!is_null($supervisor_id) && $index != -1) {

                $users[$index]['children'][] = $node;

                $nestedKeys[] = $node['user_id'];
            }
        }

        return $users;
    }
```

That method accepts a `$users` that is a collection comes from `User::all()` for example, that created a response like this But the result is not what I want:

```
[
    {
        "user_id": 1,
        "supervisor": null,
        "name": "ahmad",
        "family": "badpey",
        "full_name": "ahmad badpey",
        "children": [
            {
                "user_id": 7,
                "supervisor": {
                    "user_id": 1,
                    "name": "ahmad",
                    "family": "badpey",
                    "full_name": "ahmad badpey"
                },
                "name": "ali",
                "family": "nasiri arani",
                "full_name": "ali nasiri arani"
            },
            {
                "user_id": 8,
                "supervisor": {
                    "user_id": 1,
                    "name": "ahmad",
                    "family": "badpey",
                    "full_name": "ahmad badpey"
                },
                "name": "مصطفی",
                "family": "زاهدی",
                "full_name": "مصطفی زاهدی"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "user_id": 7,
        "supervisor": {
            "user_id": 1,
            "name": "ahmad",
            "family": "badpey",
            "full_name": "ahmad badpey"
        },
        "name": "ali",
        "family": "nasiri arani",
        "full_name": "ali nasiri arani"
    },
    {
        "user_id": 8,
        "supervisor": {
            "user_id": 1,
            "name": "ahmad",
            "family": "badpey",
            "full_name": "ahmad badpey"
        },
        "name": "مصطفی",
        "family": "زاهدی",
        "full_name": "مصطفی زاهدی",
        "children": [
            {
                "user_id": 9,
                "supervisor": {
                    "user_id": 8,
                    "name": "مصطفی",
                    "family": "زاهدی",
                    "full_name": "مصطفی زاهدی"
                },
                "name": "حسین",
                "family": "قناتی",
                "full_name": "حسین قناتی"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "user_id": 9,
        "supervisor": {
            "user_id": 8,
            "name": "مصطفی",
            "family": "زاهدی",
            "full_name": "مصطفی زاهدی"
        },
        "name": "حسین",
        "family": "قناتی",
        "full_name": "حسین قناتی"
    }
]
```

As you can see created structure is not correct because subordinate users comes Separate again.

What is the best approch to create what I want for model with similar structure?

Comment: so basically are you looking for a query whereIn you can get a supervisor for any employee and all employees for a supervisor?

Comment: yes, but not only for a specific user. may a user has some employees that each or them have their own

Comment: so you always  want a supervisor of a user  ? either he's a user or a supervisor right ?

Answer (score 0):

This is something which I tried in ruby on Rails but not laravel but I think it should work here also.. basically you need a self join..so in the User model you can have 2 relationships..

public function supervisor(){
   App/User::belongsTo(App/User::class, 'supervisor_id')
}

public function reportees(){
   App/User::hasMany(App/User::class)
}

Please correct any syntax errors and try this and see if that does what you are looking for

Comment: in this case if I want to get reportees of a supervisor should call $user->with('reportees') that returns only level 1 of those and if to get other nested reportees must call something like $user->with('reportees.reportees'). I thinks your solution is not appropriate for nested hierarchical.

Answer (score 0):

This type of relationship is a [Tree Structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_structure) or [Nested Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model), with the user's represented as nodes and leaves. At the top is the boss man, or the root node, and everyone else branching out below him.

Here is a package I'd suggest you consider: [eloquent-tree](https://github.com/AdrianSkierniewski/eloquent-tree)

You can traverse a tree in both directions from any node using:

```
$collection = $node->findAncestors()->get();

$collection = $node->findDescendants()->get();
```

Fetching all relationships is simply:

```
Tree::getLeaves();
```

And the outcome of generating a tree:

```
 Tree::mapArray(
    array(
        array(
            'children' => array(
                array(
                    'children' => array(
                        array(
                            'children' => array(
                                array(
                                    'children' => array()
                                ),
                                array(
                                    'children' => array()
                                )
                            )
                        ),
                        array(
                            'children' => array()
                        )
                    )
                ),
                array(
                    'children' => array()
                )
            )
        ),
        array(
            'children' => array()
        ),
        array(
            'children' => array()
        )
     )
 );
```

Another popular solution can be found here: [laravel-nestedset](https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset)